# Neo4j Reset node Id counter

Tags: transactions, neo4j, cypher

I am executing cypher queries to create new nodes in java.

> CREATE (n:user{name: 'ray', email: '@something.com'}) RETURN n

```
  try (Transaction tx = server.graphDb1.beginTx())
        {        
            try
            {
               Result result = server.graphDb1.execute(readString);                        
                       while (result.hasNext())
                        {
```

The Problem I have is, that after execute

Executing this three times will result in

> n: Node[0];  n: Node[1];  n: Node[2]

In case of transaction success everything is great. In case of transaction failure the nodes won't be saved. 
But the node ids are reserved.

The next three requests will result in:

> n: Node[3];  n: Node[4];  n: Node[5];

So I have 6 node ids but only 3 nodes. Is there a way to reset the counter after a transaction failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node id (and its assignment mechanism) is a completely internal thing that you as a database user should not care about at all. The only thing to remember is not to store a node id anywhere in a third party system.

Depending on the Neo4j version the unused ids will get reused after a restart - but don't rely on this implementation detail.

Comment: Is there a problem having 3 Neo4j Cluster containing data with different ids? Don't Relationships connect to Nodes with the help of Ids? - Don't I need to save the ids anywhere to make sure all 3 Clusters receive the same data?

Comment: In a Neo4j cluster the same node has the same id on each cluster member. Clustering is fully transparent to the user - it's a implementation detail.

Comment: Only when you use the ha mode,  not when I implement my own cluster

Comment: Because I want master-master replication using deferred update and it's my bachelors thesis...